# Any better panel layout for this situation

Tags: xaml, layout, panel, stackpanel

My page layout requirement is such that, it requires 3 rows. First and third row contains some buttons whereas middle row contains a data grid. This data grid is what will occupy most of space. My page root element is Grid with following row definitions.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The first and third row is just a StackPanel whereas middle row is DataGrid itself. Problem is that when user reize the windows this dooesn't scale very well. Are there any other panels that may be better fit for this scenario?

Comment: What part doesn't scale?

Comment: What are you working in? Dockpanel would accomplish the same thing as what Lukkha shows below (which is a correct answer btw) but there's not really any difference in amount of markup or end result except that Grid's probably a little more efficient at the measuring so a little less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data grid to use most of the space, use the following XAML

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```